Not able to run my org's Azure OpenAI API with SpaCy-LLM
I am trying to run spacy-llm with my organization's azure openai api that they have provided me.
But since I am pretty beginner in Python, I guess I am not writing the config file correctly, and hence getting the 403 Forbidden error.
I am not able to understand how to introduce the default_headers parameter in spacy-llm because I know that this is one of the security parts in authenticating the api.
The .env file that my org's IT has provided looks like this:
AZURE_OPENAI_KEY = "your-key"
base_url = "https://xyz.abc.com/200137912"
api_version = "2024-02-15-preview"
Model = "gpt-4-1106"

And then the config file that I have written from whatever I could understand looks like this:
[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["llm"]

[components]

[components.llm]
factory = "llm"

[components.llm.task]
@llm_tasks = "spacy.NER.v3"
labels = ["Main Organization of Text", "All Other Organizations"]

[components.llm.model]
@llm_models = "spacy.Azure.v1"
name = "gpt-4"
deployment_name = "200137912"
base_url = "https://xyz.abc.com/200137912"
model_type = "chat"

And below is the code I am running:
import os
from spacy_llm.util import assemble
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

AZURE_OPENAI_KEY = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_KEY")

base_url = os.getenv("base_url")
api_version = os.getenv("api_version")
model = os.getenv("Model")

auth_headers = {
    "200137912-Subscription-Key": AZURE_OPENAI_KEY
}

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key = AZURE_OPENAI_KEY,
    api_version = api_version,
    default_headers=auth_headers,
    azure_endpoint = base_url
)

nlp = assemble("config.cfg")

And after running this last command I get HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden
I am trying to use my organization's azure open ai api with spacy-llm.
I am expecting that someone will help me in knowing how to pass headers to spacy-llm so that authentication can occur properly and then maybe it might run.
Below is the full error:
{
    "name": "ValueError",
    "message": "Expected object or value",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:103, in AzureOpenAI.__call__.<locals>._request(json_data)
    102 try:
--> 103     r.raise_for_status()
    104 except HTTPError as ex:

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests\\models.py:1024, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1023 if http_error_msg:
-> 1024     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://atlas.<mycompanyname>.com/200137912/openai/deployments/200137912/chat/completions?api-version=2023-05-15

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 nlp = assemble(\"config.cfg\")

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\util.py:48, in assemble(config_path, overrides)
     46 config_path = Path(config_path)
     47 config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides, interpolate=False)
---> 48 return assemble_from_config(config)

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\util.py:28, in assemble_from_config(config)
     22 def assemble_from_config(config: Config) -> Language:
     23     \"\"\"Assemble a spaCy pipeline from a confection Config object.
     24 
     25     config (Config): Config to load spaCy pipeline from.
     26     RETURNS (Language): An initialized spaCy pipeline.
     27     \"\"\"
---> 28     nlp = load_model_from_config(config, auto_fill=True)
     29     config = config.interpolate()
     30     sourced = get_sourced_components(config)

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy\\util.py:587, in load_model_from_config(config, meta, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, auto_fill, validate)
    584 # This will automatically handle all codes registered via the languages
    585 # registry, including custom subclasses provided via entry points
    586 lang_cls = get_lang_class(nlp_config[\"lang\"])
--> 587 nlp = lang_cls.from_config(
    588     config,
    589     vocab=vocab,
    590     disable=disable,
    591     enable=enable,
    592     exclude=exclude,
    593     auto_fill=auto_fill,
    594     validate=validate,
    595     meta=meta,
    596 )
    597 return nlp

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy\\language.py:1889, in Language.from_config(cls, config, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, meta, auto_fill, validate)
   1886     factory = pipe_cfg.pop(\"factory\")
   1887     # The pipe name (key in the config) here is the unique name
   1888     # of the component, not necessarily the factory
-> 1889     nlp.add_pipe(
   1890         factory,
   1891         name=pipe_name,
   1892         config=pipe_cfg,
   1893         validate=validate,
   1894         raw_config=raw_config,
   1895     )
   1896 else:
   1897     assert \"source\" in pipe_cfg

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy\\language.py:821, in Language.add_pipe(self, factory_name, name, before, after, first, last, source, config, raw_config, validate)
    817     pipe_component, factory_name = self.create_pipe_from_source(
    818         factory_name, source, name=name
    819     )
    820 else:
--> 821     pipe_component = self.create_pipe(
    822         factory_name,
    823         name=name,
    824         config=config,
    825         raw_config=raw_config,
    826         validate=validate,
    827     )
    828 pipe_index = self._get_pipe_index(before, after, first, last)
    829 self._pipe_meta[name] = self.get_factory_meta(factory_name)

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy\\language.py:709, in Language.create_pipe(self, factory_name, name, config, raw_config, validate)
    706 cfg = {factory_name: config}
    707 # We're calling the internal _fill here to avoid constructing the
    708 # registered functions twice
--> 709 resolved = registry.resolve(cfg, validate=validate)
    710 filled = registry.fill({\"cfg\": cfg[factory_name]}, validate=validate)[\"cfg\"]
    711 filled = Config(filled)

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\confection\\__init__.py:760, in registry.resolve(cls, config, schema, overrides, validate)
    751 @classmethod
    752 def resolve(
    753     cls,
   (...)
    758     validate: bool = True,
    759 ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
--> 760     resolved, _ = cls._make(
    761         config, schema=schema, overrides=overrides, validate=validate, resolve=True
    762     )
    763     return resolved

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\confection\\__init__.py:809, in registry._make(cls, config, schema, overrides, resolve, validate)
    807 if not is_interpolated:
    808     config = Config(orig_config).interpolate()
--> 809 filled, _, resolved = cls._fill(
    810     config, schema, validate=validate, overrides=overrides, resolve=resolve
    811 )
    812 filled = Config(filled, section_order=section_order)
    813 # Check that overrides didn't include invalid properties not in config

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\confection\\__init__.py:864, in registry._fill(cls, config, schema, validate, resolve, parent, overrides)
    862     schema.__fields__[key] = copy_model_field(field, Any)
    863 promise_schema = cls.make_promise_schema(value, resolve=resolve)
--> 864 filled[key], validation[v_key], final[key] = cls._fill(
    865     value,
    866     promise_schema,
    867     validate=validate,
    868     resolve=resolve,
    869     parent=key_parent,
    870     overrides=overrides,
    871 )
    872 reg_name, func_name = cls.get_constructor(final[key])
    873 args, kwargs = cls.parse_args(final[key])

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\confection\\__init__.py:881, in registry._fill(cls, config, schema, validate, resolve, parent, overrides)
    878     getter = cls.get(reg_name, func_name)
    879     # We don't want to try/except this and raise our own error
    880     # here, because we want the traceback if the function fails.
--> 881     getter_result = getter(*args, **kwargs)
    882 else:
    883     # We're not resolving and calling the function, so replace
    884     # the getter_result with a Promise class
    885     getter_result = Promise(
    886         registry=reg_name, name=func_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs
    887     )

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\registry.py:109, in azure_openai(deployment_name, name, base_url, model_type, config, strict, max_tries, interval, max_request_time, api_version)
     69 @registry.llm_models(\"spacy.Azure.v1\")
     70 def azure_openai(
     71     deployment_name: str,
   (...)
     80     api_version: str = \"2023-05-15\",
     81 ) -> Callable[[Iterable[Iterable[str]]], Iterable[Iterable[str]]]:
     82     \"\"\"Returns Azure OpenAI instance for models deployed on Azure's OpenAI service using REST to prompt API.
     83 
     84     Docs on OpenAI models supported by Azure:
   (...)
    107     DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/large-language-models#models
    108     \"\"\"
--> 109     return AzureOpenAI(
    110         deployment_name=deployment_name,
    111         name=name,
    112         endpoint=base_url,
    113         config=config,
    114         strict=strict,
    115         max_tries=max_tries,
    116         interval=interval,
    117         max_request_time=max_request_time,
    118         api_version=api_version,
    119         model_type=model_type,
    120         context_length=None,
    121     )

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:36, in AzureOpenAI.__init__(self, deployment_name, name, endpoint, config, strict, max_tries, interval, max_request_time, model_type, context_length, api_version)
     34 self._api_version = api_version
     35 self._deployment_name = deployment_name
---> 36 super().__init__(
     37     name=name,
     38     endpoint=endpoint,
     39     config=config,
     40     strict=strict,
     41     max_tries=max_tries,
     42     interval=interval,
     43     max_request_time=max_request_time,
     44     context_length=context_length,
     45 )

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\base.py:68, in REST.__init__(self, name, endpoint, config, strict, max_tries, interval, max_request_time, context_length)
     65 assert self._interval > 0
     66 assert self._max_request_time > 0
---> 68 self._verify_auth()

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:80, in AzureOpenAI._verify_auth(self)
     78     self([[\"test\"]])
     79 except ValueError as err:
---> 80     raise err

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:78, in AzureOpenAI._verify_auth(self)
     76 def _verify_auth(self) -> None:
     77     try:
---> 78         self([[\"test\"]])
     79     except ValueError as err:
     80         raise err

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:132, in AzureOpenAI.__call__(self, prompts)
    128 if self._model_type == ModelType.CHAT:
    129     # Note: this is yet (2023-10-05) untested, as Azure doesn't seem to allow the deployment of a chat model
    130     # yet.
    131     for prompt in prompts_for_doc:
--> 132         responses = _request(
    133             {\"messages\": [{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": prompt}]}
    134         )
    135         if \"error\" in responses:
    136             return responses[\"error\"]

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\spacy_llm\\models\\rest\\azure\\model.py:105, in AzureOpenAI.__call__.<locals>._request(json_data)
    103     r.raise_for_status()
    104 except HTTPError as ex:
--> 105     res_content = srsly.json_loads(r.content.decode(\"utf-8\"))
    106     # Include specific error message in exception.
    107     raise ValueError(
    108         f\"Request to Azure OpenAI API failed: \"
    109         f\"{res_content.get('error', {}).get('message', str(res_content))}\"
    110     ) from ex

File c:\\Users\\virgup01\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\srsly\\_json_api.py:39, in json_loads(data)
     37 if data == \"-\":
     38     raise ValueError(\"Expected object or value\")
---> 39 return ujson.loads(data)

ValueError: Expected object or value"
}


Can you supply the whole traceback to your error?

Edited the question and added whole error.

Hard to tell, but your base_url doesn't match the pattern I'm using (or what's mentioned on the spacy page) -> https://spacy.io/api/large-language-models#models-rest
From the docs:

Deployed Azure OpenAI models are reachable via a resource-specific base URL, usually of the form https://{resource}.openai.azure.com. Hence the URL has to be specified via the base_url argument.

Idk if that's the issue, but worth looking into.
You may also have to add the api_version to your config file.
